# Observer change Quote Magento

Tags: php, ajax, magento, header, checkout

I need to change grandtotal and basetotal values in quote, i added observer on checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method, it works, i already wrote logic for changing values, but main problem that, i can't save quota and it returns me not edited values. I guess the main problem that headers were sent, but in which way i can do it?

```
public function checkTotals(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{   
    $quote      = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote();

    $grandTotal = 1

    $quote->setData('grand_total', $grandTotal);
    $quote->setData('base_grand_total', $grandTotal);
    $quote->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't solved. I had problem with PayPal API and when one of extensions was adding 2% to the price because of PayPal, it broke the API call to the paypal. The problem were in save method that recalculate totals in Quota takes again the values from cart and you can't just change the prices or anything else. If you want to make anything like add few percents to the price, you need to create some item in quota or price rule, or just hidden item in cart, that will allow to change.